# Hiding <TableViewRow> in Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, visible, titanium-alloy

Ok, this is (or ought to be) straightforward - unless I am overlooking something (which probably is the case).

I have created a very simple example:

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <TableView>
            <TableViewSection>
                <TableViewRow>
                    <Label>Row 1</Label>
                </TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow visible="false">
                    <Label>Row 2</Label>
                </TableViewRow>
                <TableViewRow id="row3">
                    <Label>Row 3</Label>
                </TableViewRow>
            </TableViewSection>
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

... and index.tss:

```
"#row3":{visible:false}

"Window": {
    top: 60
}
```

I would have expected that row 2 and row 3 were NOT displayed. However, all rows display (in the iOS Simulator).

I have read about similar issues in earlier versions of Titanium Studio. The workaround from these 2-4 years old posts were to set the height of the tableviewrow to 1 (as 0 is ignored). However, this still shows part of the label. Then I can hide the label (visible="false" workst for that!) and then I only see a "thin" row. But with the standard view row separators you still see that there is a row....

So, what am I doing wrong here??

I use the TableView layout to create a form for entering data - and some of the rows should only be shown to the user if a switch is set. Is there a better pattern for doing this?

I am on Studio 3.4.1GA, Mac OS X 10.10.1 and using the 8.1 iOS in simulator ;-)

Thank you in advance!

/John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question in the developers' Q&A on appcelerator.com. I ended up getting a couple of suggestions as to how to solve it - both using the Alloy markup. The best solution is along the lines of what Lucky Luke suggests - but using Alloy instead of creating the TableView using the traditional coding style.

Here is a [link to the solution I chose](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/179444/how-to-hide-a-tableviewrow---or-alternative-for-form-layout#answer-284264).

Sorry that I hadn't come around and added the link here before now.

/John

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best approach but you could try populating your section inside your controller.

You will populate an array with all (and only) the rows you would like to show each time and then update the `rows` attribute of your TableViewSection.
I quote some pseudocode:

```
var section = Ti.UI.createTableSection({...});
var row1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({...});
var row2 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({...});
var row3 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({...});

var rows_options = [];
if (show_less) rows_options.push(row1, row2); //"hide" 3rd row
else rows_options.push(row1, row2, row3); //show all 3 rows

section.rows = rows_options;
```

Alternatively, consider not using a tableview, if it is not necessary, and instead build your own view with `layout: vertical` hosting your rows that will much simulate the same use. In this case I believe the `visible` hack will work for you.